# OpenGL - Can only draw to first side of cubemap

Tags: c++, opengl, depth

For some reason trying to draw on any side other than the first one seems to have no effect.

This is how I'm creating the cubemap:

```
GLuint frameBuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1,&frameBuffer);

GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1,&texture);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE,GL_LUMINANCE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC,GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE,GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X  +i,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,size,size,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X  +i,texture,0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
}
```

Writing to / Reading from the cubemap:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,texture);

float *pixels = new float[size *size];
for(int j=0;j<(size *size);j++)
    pixels[j] = 1.f;

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X +i,texture,0);

    glTexSubImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X +i,
        0,
        0,0,
        size,size,
        GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
        GL_FLOAT,
        &pixels[0]
    );
}

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBuffer);
for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
{
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X +j,texture,0);
    glReadPixels(0,0,size,size,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,&pixels[0]);
    for(int k=0;k<(size *size);k++)
    {
        if(pixels[k] != 1.f)
        {
            // Incorrect pixel
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

All this should be doing is set the depth component of all pixels of all sides of the cubemap to 1 and then read them out again. However, when reading the pixels, it seems that it only worked for the first side, for all other sides the depth component is 0.

Comment: You do not have to attach your texture to the FBO to fill it with data using `glTexSubImage2D (...)`. There is really no reason at all to call `glFramebufferTexture2D (...)` in your first loop, it will decrease performance because validation and other unnecessary things occur whenever you modify an FBO's attachments. And honestly, since you are not even using FBOs for the purpose of drawing here, you should drop the FBO altogether and just use `glGetTexImage (...)`.